# Updating a sequence of Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, sequence

I've encountered an exercise that requires to solve the problem with `dict.update()`.

> Body of the task: The dict.update method merges two dicts. Write a
> function that takes any number of dicts and returns a dict that
> reflects the combination of all of them. If the same key appears in
> more than one dict, then the most recently merged dict’s value should
> appear in the output.

I managed to write a code for 2 inputs:

```
def d_update(first, second):
    first = first.update(second)
    return d1

d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
d2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 5}

print(d_update(d1,d2)) #outout is {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 5}
```

But I am struggling with arranging a multiple sequence of dicts. Tried to use:

```
def d_update(*sequence):
    for D in sequence:
        D = D.update(D)
    return D
```

but it returns `None`.

What should I do?

Comment: ```D.update(D)``` ```.update``` is an in place function. It returns ```None```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is absolutely correct. You just made a minor mistake.

`.update` is an inplace function. It returns `None` or nothing.
By doing `D=D.update(D)`, you are assigning `None` to `D`

Simply do `D.update(D)`

Here is the updated code.

```
def d_update(*sequence):
    for D in sequence:
        D.update(D)
    return D

d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
d2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 5}

print(d_update(d1,d2)) #outout is {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 5}
```

Comment: That's surprising to know now... How do I know if the function is an inplace or not?

Comment: I mean, sometimes I miss the part where I have to assign an action to variable, sometimes I do it and that is incorrect

How do I know when to pick the correct one?